# how to add a image in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
PS D:\flutter new\flutter_application_1> flutter build apk
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 28, column 3: Could not find expected ':' for simple key.
   ╷
28 │   -images/pic.png
   │   ^
   ╵
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at D:\flutter new\flutter_application_1\pubspec.yaml
```

and this is my Pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: namer_app
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 0.0.1+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.4 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  english_words: ^4.0.0
  provider: ^6.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
  -images/pic.png
```

Comment: Where is the `images/pic.png` located? In the asset directory?

Answer (score 2):

Do you follow the example commented in pubspec.yaml?

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - icons/
    - images/pic.png
```

**What's wrong on your side**

```
  assets:
  -images/pic.png
  ^ (this alignment)
```

You must align every line and space (Dash, space)